# What do you call those things you use in LaTeX to format text?

Tags: macros, naming, learning

I want many times to ask questions but I don't know what to call those. Are they called tags? Commands? Formatters?

Example:

```
\example{example}
```

I know my question is general but that's what the question is for. To get out of generality.

Comment: They are referred to as `macro` or a `command`. Is that what you are looking for?  And, [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: @Peter I think yes. I should probably give an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In LaTeX text formatting is done with a **macro**, also sometimes referred to as a **command**. These are really just shorthands for a more complicated sequence of commands, and are useful as they are easier to remember, and also help to separate content from formatting.

You can define you own macros via `\newcommand`, and that will behave similar to the ones that are already built in or loaded via `\usepackage` commands.

So, in the case of your example:

```
\example{Derivative}
```

the `\example` is the command, and `Derivative` is a **parameter** or **argument** for the macro. So, if the command was defined as, for example:

```
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\textbf{Example: \Large #1}}
```

then the above command would produce:

[image]

Note that `\newcommand`, `\textbf` and `\Large` are also examples of macros that were used here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\textbf{Example: \Large #1}}

\begin{document}
\example{Derivative}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update:** As @Werner/@Martin correctly points out the more formal terminology is **control sequence**, or **primitive** for the case where these are defined in the TeX, but in asking questions here either should be fine.

Comment: In fact, the formal name is "command sequence," since they contain a sequence of commands and/or primitives (which are commands themselves).

Comment: @Werner: No! I used to think so too, but they are called *control sequences*. They are called *commands* by LaTeX, e.g. like in `\newcommand`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I was probably thinking "control" but wrote down "command"; as you say, I'm so used to `\...command` *control* sequences! Thanks for correcting me...